# Error with solr cloud most probable out of file handlers

Tags: java, solr

Can someone help me with this error, I am using solr cloud 5 and getting this

```
    WARN  - 2015-09-10 06:28:17.804; [   ]    
    org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractConnector$Acceptor;
    java.io.IOException: Too many open files
    at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.accept0(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.accept(ServerSocketChannelImpl.java:241)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.ServerConnector.accept(ServerConnector.java:377)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractConnector$Acceptor.run(AbstractConnector.java:500)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:635)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:555)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
```

Unable to understand how to solve this?

Comment: When is this exception coming?

Comment: Too many file descriptors have been created while indexing in solr cloud. The setting of ulimit will be a temporary solution, can this be somehow solved with solr cloud?

Answer (score 0):

Each index contains multiple segments, and each segment contains multiple parts, each stored as a separate file. You can set `useCompoundFile` to `true` in **solrconfig.xml** . The compound file format stuffs all of the segment parts into a single file. It's not as efficient as the non-compound format though.

If you are using an higher value for `mergeFactor` parameter in solrconfig.xml, you might want to reduce it. So there will be fewer segment files to merge for the solr background process. keep in mind, the mergeFactor have advantage and dis-advantage to solr indexing and searching. Please check [Merging Index Segments](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/IndexConfig+in+SolrConfig#IndexConfiginSolrConfig-MergingIndexSegments) for more information.